# Turbo Power - SongBeamer or SourceForge for Delphi XE?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

It looks like the SongBeamer site which put up some nice ports for the TurboPower OpenSource projects for Delphi 2009+ are now being outdated with some recent updates in SourceForge. But, then again, maybe not? Which versions are best used with Delphi XE?

I'm most interested in Abbrevia, LockBox, and Async Pro.  It looks like Abbrevia-SourceForge, AsynPro-SongBeamer, LockBox..?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Abbrevia** is much better on SourceForge.  The SongBeamer version was based on unstable code from mid-2008.  I started maintaining the project in 2009 and the official 3.05 stable release had a lot of cleanup and fixes after that.  v4.0 was released in March 2011, and added new features, include full support for Unicode filenames in zips, bzip2 archives, and decompression support for most of the new zipx compression algorithms (LZMA, bzip2, PPMd, WavPack).  The current Subversion trunk also has Zip64 support and much better splitting/spanning support.

**Async Pro** appears to be better on SourceForge, but it's a bit of a mix.  Officially only a handful of components have been updated to Unicode.  In the SourceForge release the admin added $IFDEFs to keep the remaining files from compiling, while on SongBeamer they may still compile but might not be correct.  There have been a few releases on SongBeamer since the SourceForge 5.0 release, so there may be some fixes not in the official release, but it's not based on the 5.0 release, so they're both missing stuff.

**LockBox 2** is better on SongBeamer.  The SourceForge version hasn't been updated with Unicode support at all.  The SourceForge site does include a **LockBox 3** project that supports Delphi 2007 through Delphi XE, but it's entirely new, incompatible code, so the only thing they share is the name.  It is being updated though, unlike LB2.

**Orpheus** is better on SourceForge and incorporates all of the fixes from SongBeamer.

**Office Partner** has had a Unicode update posted in the SourceForge project's forums, but doesn't have a maintainer, so it's not official released or in the SVN repository.  Not available on SongBeamer.

**OnGuard** and **SysTools** are the same on both sites.

**ShellShock** has Unicode support in the SourceForge Subversion repository.

**XML Partner** has the SongBeamer code committed to the SourceForge Subversion repository.

**TP Essentials** is better on SongBeamer.

The rest of the TurboPower projects SourceForge projects are dead.

Answer (score 8):

I am the "owner" of the Turbopower projects on SourceForge. They are all in various states of development, but the most popular ones are XE ready.

I confess that I don't know the exact state of any individual project, but I can say that SourceForge is the best place to get the most recent and up to date "official" version.

Comment: I just ran a compare on LockBox2 and it looks to me that SongBeamer's is the one to use.

Comment: Abbrevia has seem some action and a 4.0 release has recently been updated on SourceForge so it would appear that SourceForge is the way to go with this package.

Comment: is it possible if you provide some additional information about LockBox status? It appears there is a lot of misinformation about it.

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know, the SourceForge versions of the projects are currently actively being maintained, under the direction of Nick Hodges.

Answer (score 3):

Stay away from LockBox. Version 2.x in now really outdated (but for very simple cryptography needs), while version 3.x developer has somehow "stolen" the LockBox name, writing another library not compatible, and its quality doesn't look good.
Moreover IMHO he has no rights to change the license, only the Initial Developer - Turbo Power - can relicense under different ones, if he didn't like MPL 1.1 he could have created his own library without taking Turbo Power's Lockbox name and Sourceforge project. Thereby you may end up using a library with an invalid license, especially if you plan to use it under GPL terms.
If you have needs for good cryptography look elsewhere.

Comment: The license for LockBox 2 hasn't changed. LockBox 3 is not a fork, is a new project with a different license. See http://lockbox.seanbdurkin.id.au/tiki-view_forum_thread.php?comments_parentId=63&forumId=2 for details.

Comment: The problem with DCPCrypt: "Note: This page hasn't seen much attention in quite a while and is unlikely to for the foreseeable future… "

Comment: @Leonardo: even with a fork you have to respect the original license. And a fork would have a different name, not LockBox 3.

Comment: ELdoS SecureBlackbox is a good encryption library for Delphi, although not free.

Comment: LockBox3 is supposed to be rewritten from scratch - the only thing it shares with 2 is the base name.

Comment: As far as LockBox2 goes - it looks like SongBeamer's is the one to use.

Comment: @Leonardo: exactly, it is a new project that stole the Lockbox name and sourceforge project while the mantainer is sleeping. It would have been a different project if it had its own project on Sourceforge - and look at the file headers. They still have "The Initial Developer of the Original Code for TurboPower LockBox version 2", the developer aim is to present it as a legitimate Loxkbox evolution, for which he had no right to change the license. His project should be moved to a different one, and stop using the Lockbox name.

Comment: @ldsandon - He *hasn't* changed the license in LockBox 2. LockBox 3 is _not_ the same project. Also, I don't see how you can *steal* a SourceForge project. And regarding quality, please talk facts, not opinions. And please note that I'm not an active user of this library; I'm just intrigued by these bold statements.

Comment: BTW, I do agree there is a lot of confusion with this library.

Answer (score 1):

The sourceforge version of AsyncPro doesn't add the BCB components either - these seem to have suffered a lot since TP opensourced. I had to build packages for this a couple of times to support various versions of RAD studio. Haven't checked the latest songbeamer build.